# How to subscribe to a model in django channels rest framework?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-channels

I'm trying to subscribe for changes in a model using Django Channels Rest Framework. I've been following the example at https://djangochannelsrestframework.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/model_observer.html and at latest following question: [How to subscribe to all instances of a model in django channels rest framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63915853/how-to-subscribe-to-all-instances-of-a-model-in-django-channels-rest-framework). However, I'm not receiving updates via WebSockets when the models are updated.

I'm having consumser set as below:

```
# consumers.py

from djangochannelsrestframework.consumers import AsyncAPIConsumer
from djangochannelsrestframework.observer import model_observer
from .models import User, Comment


class ModelConsumerObserver(AsyncAPIConsumer):
    async def accept(self, **kwargs):
        print("WebSocket Connect 1")
        await super().accept()
        print("WebSocket Connect 2")
        await self.model_change.subscribe()
        print("WebSocket Connect 3")

    @model_observer(Comment)
    async def model_change(self, message, **kwargs):
        print("Model Observer 1")
        await self.send_json(message)
        print("Model Observer 2")
```

I'm trying to subscribe for Comment-model as in the example in documentation. However, I'm not receiving the updates on model. On my side there is currently no authentication, no exception on server. The local server console shows:

```
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
June 06, 2021 - 10:11:10
Django version 3.2.3, using settings 'websocket.settings'
Starting ASGI/Channels version 3.0.3 development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
HTTP GET / 200 [0.01, 127.0.0.1:64527]
WebSocket HANDSHAKING /ws/my-consumer/ [127.0.0.1:64528]
WebSocket Connect 1
WebSocket CONNECT /ws/my-consumer/ [127.0.0.1:64528]
WebSocket Connect 2
WebSocket Connect 3
```

I'm not sure, but it mos def seems like it is not ever getting to the model observer. Any ideas?